# Change variable description in Xcode variable view

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, debugging

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the description of variables in the Xcode debugger for example:
[image: Xcode Debugger]

I'd like to change the text in the red boxes to depend on the object itself. Kind of how the NSArray has @"10 elements" as it's description.

Comment: Implement the `description` method on your custom class.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: You can change what appears in the console, not in the variables list.

Comment: @matt :( I'm sad now. Come on apple we need this!

Comment: You can also provide Quick Look rendering (for eyeball at bottom)

Answer (score 3):

From Xcode Help:

> To edit the summary format of a variable, Control-click the variable and choose Edit Summary Format… from the shortcut menu.
>
> In the popover, enter a valid LLDB expression and click Done. This expression overrides the default formatter and is used to create a summary for all variables of this type.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the summary to class in debug console.

type summary add UITableViewCell -s "${var%@}"

That will print description instead of the memory address.

Comment: Don't forget to specify the module for Swift types: `Module.Type`